# Error in pyomo expression generation with sum using python 3.6

Tags: python-3.6, pyomo

I am using pyomo Pyomo 5.1.1 (CPython 3.6.0 on Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64)
under Python 3.6, and I get an error message when I want to build an Expression in a model using a summation.
Here is a minimal example :

```
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
model=ConcreteModel()
model.H=RangeSet(0,23)
model.x=Var(model.H)
E=summation(model.x)
```

I get the following error :

"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/b67777/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo/core/base/util.py", line 86, in summation
    ans += item
  File "/home/b67777/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo/core/base/numvalue.py", line 537, in __iadd__
    return generate_expression(_iadd,self,other)
  File "/home/b67777/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo/core/base/expr_coopr3.py", line 977, in generate_expression
    _self = _generate_expression__clone_if_needed(_self, 1)
  File "/home/b67777/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo/core/base/expr_coopr3.py", line 918, in _generate_expression__clone_if_needed
    % ( getrefcount(obj) - UNREFERENCED_EXPR_COUNT, ))
RuntimeError: Expression entered generate_expression() with too few references (0<0); this is indicative of a SERIOUS ERROR in the expression reuse detection scheme.
```

"

I get the same error if I replaced the "summation" by a loop  over h in model.H.

The bug has been noticed also here : https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/103

Is there a simple way to fix this, other than stepping back to older version of Python ?

Thank you very much for your help,

Paulin

Answer (score 4):

Pyomo only supports Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3, 3.4, and 3.5.

Python 3.6 changed the internal call stack, which invalidated the internal "magic numbers" that Pyomo uses for detecting when an expression is being pointed to by extra variables (i.e., it is potentially being reused in multiple expressions - something that is not allowed by the Pyomo expression trees).  The developers are working on a fix (in the `pyomo4-expressions` branch).  Until that fix is merged back into master and released, the only alternative is to install one of the supported Python versions.

---

**Update** [3 April 17]: The fix was merged back into `master` on 7 March 2017.  Pyomo should support Python 3.6 in the next patch release.

---

**Update** [14 May 17]: Pyomo 5.2 has been released, which provides full support for Python 3.6